# Mutation error when saving redux store. All copied and saved

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

First of all, in the page, the data object is changed with usestate and the screen is drawn! Save the scroll value and data when leaving the page to remember the scroll value on the page. As a result of the confirmation, the changed value is saved, but when I come back, this error keeps popping up.

```js
const mainPageCopy = { ...store.mainPage };
mainPageList.forEach(function (value, index) {
  mainPageCopy.list[index] = value;
  mainPageCopy.scroll = document.querySelector(".body").scrollTop;
});
dispatch({ type: "mainPage/set", payload: mainPageCopy })
router.push(`/product/${value.product_seq}`);
```

This is not even saved to the store

[image]

Comment: I didn't know forEach couldn't do asynchronous operations. I'm so lacking I don't know how... help me...

Comment: There's nothing async here though. I think all you want is `mainPageList.foreach((value, index) => { ... }); dispatch(...);`

Comment: But if you do that, it won't even be saved to the store. Could it have been the wrong way? help me

Comment: I get the same error before saving

Comment: sorry. I have corrected it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is one relating to shallow copies. This code...

```js
const mainPageCopy = { ...store.mainPage };
```

creates a shallow copy of `store.mainPage`. Since the `list` property is an array, the copy will reference the same object in the `store`. Making changes to them in the `forEach()` loop is what's triggering the error.

Try this instead

```js
const mainPageCopy = {
  ...store.mainPage,
  scroll: document.querySelector('.body').scrollTop,
  list: [
    ...mainPageList, 
    ...store.mainPage.list.slice(mainPageList.length),
  ],
};

dispatch({ type: "mainPage/set", payload: mainPageCopy });
```

This replaces the first elements of `list` with all the elements in `mainPageList`, leaving the rest of `store.mainPage.list` as-is. There was also no need to assign `scroll` within a loop.

Comment: phil can yo help me...?